# Excel Formula to skip blank cells

Tags: arrays, excel-formula

I have Excel data in columns need to remove blank cells: Formula not working

**Current Data:**

```
ABC (blank cell) XYZ KLM (blank cell) 123
```

**Output required:**

```
ABC XYZ KLM 123
```

**Formula I am using:**

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(B$2:G$2,SMALL(IF(B$2:G$2<>"",COLUMN(B$2:G$2)-COLUMN(B$2)+1),COLUMNS($L2:$L2))),"")}
```

**Output Getting from this formula:**

```
ABC XYZ XYZ KLM 123 123
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel skip blank or 0-valued cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512537/excel-skip-blank-or-0-valued-cells)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the answer, its working fine:**

> {=IFERROR(INDEX($B2:$G2,SMALL(IF($B2:$G2<>"",COLUMN($B2:$G2)-COLUMN($B2)+1),COLUMNS($L2:L2))),"")}

Comment: Please choose this as the accepted answer if you have solved your own problem.